# How do I pass a template as a template parameter to a template?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I'm trying to write something like:

```
          // I don't know how this particular syntax should look...
template<typename template<typename Ty> FunctorT>
Something MergeSomething(const Something& lhs, const Something& rhs)
{
    Something result(lhs);
    if (lhs.IsUnsigned() && rhs.IsUnsigned())
    {
        result.SetUnsigned(FunctorT<unsigned __int64>()(lhs.UnsignedValue(), rhs.UnsignedValue()));
    }
    else
    {
        result.SetSigned(FunctorT<__int64>()(lhs.SignedValue(), rhs.SignedValue()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

which would be used like:

```
Something a, b;
Something c = MergeSomething<std::plus>(a, b);
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Would not a simple `template <typename Ty>` suffice and then pass `MergeSomething<typename std::plus<Something>>;` otherwise perhaps a peak under the covers of `boost::function` or `boost::bind` could give some insight.

Comment: @AJG85: No -- if you look at the example code I'm calling the template function with different template arguments inside my own function template.

Comment: Ah yes so you are I guess this is simplified code and the type determination is not so trivial in actuality. Good question I think I might have some generic storage classes which could benefit from something like this.

Comment: @AJG85: No, this is the actual code. See how I've got FunctorT<blah blah>() inside the code -- if you don't pass it as a template you're passing an instantiation rather than the template itself, which means you can't change the type attached to it.

Comment: @Billy Wouldn't the compiler simply generate a type for each instantiation anyway? If the template for `FunctorT` was defined outside and before `MergeSomething` then it would work for either and just pick the right one based on calling of `MergeSomething` ... not having to do a `switch` of `if` statement based on type is usually an advantage of template code.

Comment: @AJG85: No. The type to pass to `std::plus` is not known until runtime. Therefore I can't deduce it with templates.

Comment: Ok thanks for bearing with me, that makes sense.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is just a "template template argument". The syntax is very close to what you imagined. Here it is:

```
template< template<typename Ty> class FunctorT>
Something MergeSomething(const Something& lhs, const Something& rhs)
{
    Something result(lhs);
    if (lhs.IsUnsigned() && rhs.IsUnsigned())
    {
        result.SetUnsigned(FunctorT<unsigned __int64>()(lhs.UnsignedValue(), rhs.UnsignedValue()));
    }
    else
    {
        result.SetSigned(FunctorT<__int64>()(lhs.SignedValue(), rhs.SignedValue()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your use-case should work like you posted it.

Answer (score 14):

The way you *use* it is correct. But your function template definition itself is wrong.

It should be this:

```
template<template<typename Ty> class FunctorT> //<---here is the correction
Something MergeSomething(const Something& lhs, const Something& rhs)
```

And `Ty` is not needed. In fact, its meaningless there. You can omit it completely.

See this article by Stephen C. Dewhurst:

- [C++ Common Knowledge: Template Template Parameters](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=376878)

Comment: I think you must put a space after the first "<" for this to compile successfully

Comment: @dario_ramos: Thats okay : http://www.ideone.com/S639B. Space is needed when you write `>>` which in C++03 should be `> >`. This is fixed in C++0x.